# linq to update or insert on a csv file

Tags: c#, linq, csv, insert-update

I successfully made a c# class that uses Jet to execute a `SELECT` string on a csv file.  However, I really need an `UPDATE` and/or `INSERT` statement and Jet apparently won't allow it.  I've been looking into using LINQ, but can't seem to find any examples of an `UPDATE` clause for LINQ either.  Anyone know about this?  or perhaps a different class than LINQ that could accomplish this?

Basically, I want to read a csv file into memory and query on it (select columns, or distinct, etc), which is fine with Jet, but I also want to update rows and modify the text file.

basically:

```
UPDATE table 
SET col3 = 42 
WHERE col1='mouse', col2='dolphins';
```

and have that take effect data read from csv.

also, I can't figure out how to access columns by name with LINQ.  any advice?

so far, a constructor for my class seems to parse the file ok (I can see it in the watch and immediate windows), but I don't know how to move on from here:

```
        string Method = this.ToString();
        this.strFilePath = filePath;
        this.strDelim = delim;

        Logger.Debug("Starting", Method);
        try
        {
            fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(Ex, Method);
        }
        this.fileTable = fileLines.Select(l => l.Split(delim));
```

Ignore the 'Logger', this is an in-house class that writes things to a log for our own purposes.

Comment: FTR:  I'm hoping to avoid looping through the file myself, seems like there must be a better tool in 2016 than me writing a loop and checking the columns for the where clause

Comment: FYI, I've gotten far enough to get this to work:  `tempFt = from r in fileTable.Where(ln => !ln[0].Equals(headers[0]) && Convert.ToDouble(ln[2]) >= 42.0) select r;`, but I still want to figure out if I can update/insert/delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking can't easily be done, due to the way text files are organized.

In general, you can't arbitrarily update a text file like you can a file of records. Consider, for example, the following text file.

```
line1,43,27,Jim
line2,29,32,Keith
```

Now, you want to change the `43` on line 1 to `4300`. That involves adding two characters to the file. So you end up having to move everything after `43` down two spaces and then insert the `00`. But moving everything down two spaces requires extending the file and moving the entire text.

Text files are typically used for *sequential* access: reading and appending. Insertion or deletion affects the entire file beyond the point of modification. Unless you're going to re-write the entire file on every change, you simply do not want to use a text file for holding data that changes frequently.

Comment: I think that all makes sense to me, and I realize this would come at the cost of a lot of cpu time.  However, at this point, I have no control over data type (stuck in csv files for quite a while) yet (I hope to transition to a dbms eventually).  The files are quite small (never over 100kb), and there are no race conditions of multiple-access, so re-writing would be tolerable.  any tools out there?

Comment: @Keith: No tools that I know of. If there are no race conditions and such, why not load the whole thing into an array of lines? Every time the user makes a change, just rewrite the entire file. [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) makes quick work of that.

Comment: that would be fine by me, is there by chance a way to use linq (or similar) on the data in memory, then I can re write the files?

Comment: @Keith: LINQ doesn't modify collections. Rather, you use it to build a new collection from an existing collection. LINQ has no facility for passing a sequence and modifying individual records in-place.